Does The Individual Private Plans Encapsulate Medicare Advantage Plans?
I'd like to understand what type of plans are returned when querying the individual private plans outside of the marketplace.  Would this include Medicare advantage plans?  Or is it strictly non-government subsidized health insurance plans?

Would you mind sharing what API your question is about? Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
